# Where to learn Pyramid by following practical examples?

Tags: python, pyramid, backend

From the official website there's only things like "hello world" and a todo-list. Apparently Pyramid doesn't seem to be mainstream enough to spawn sufficient example tutorials, and I'm the kind of person that finds it more efficient to learn by following various sample projects. I think my Google-fu is not strong enough...

I'm actually pretty much brand new to back-end in general, so it would be even more helpful if someone can show me a variety of small and practical tutorials of how a Python backend works with Pyramid, all the way from setting up the configuration accordingly, passing data back and forth from the client side, and how data from the backend is hooked to the frontend template.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 4):

There are official tutorials supported by the Pylons Project.
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/#tutorials
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/index.html

There are community contributed tutorials as well, where the list of them is officially curated by the Pylons Project, but the tutorials themselves may not be official.
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-tutorials/en/latest/index.html#pyramid-tutorials

Answer (score 3):

Pyramid projects:

**Tutorias**

Pyramid Bloggr tutorial: https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_blogr

**Heavy weight**

Warehouse (the next generation Python package index in development): https://github.com/pypa/warehouse

Kotti CMS: https://github.com/Kotti/Kotti

Substance D CMS: http://www.substanced.net/